# How to install qunitjs with git on Karma's?

Tags: node.js, npm, qunit, karma-runner, karma-qunit

I'm trying to work around [this error in karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter/pull/14).

QUnit has [comitted a fix](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/350) for the error since v1.14.0, so I want to install qunit from git to work with karma-qunit.

```
npm rm qunitjs
npm i jquery/qunit
```

Then I run karma and I get an error, even though `./node_modules/qunitjs` is present with a `package.json` file:

```
$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start

module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'qunitjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (module.js:384:19)
    at initQUnit (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma-qunit/lib/index.js:7:39)
    at Array.invoke [as 0] (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at get (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at /home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:31:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at start (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:30:21)
    at invoke (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Object.exports.start (/home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:306:12)
```

The error doesn't occur when installing qunit with `npm install qunitjs`. Anyone know what's going on?

I'm using npm 1.4.16 and node 0.10.25.

Comment: quick fix: `npm rm qunitjs` `npm install github.com/jquery/qunit`  npm knows how to use github. you can also specify branches, commits, tags with the same url syntax as github.

Comment: @generalhenry that's exactly what I did. `npm i jquery/qunit` is a shortcut for `npm install github.com/jquery/qunit`. Have you tried using karma with qunit from github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this folders tree :

```
./node_modules/
    ./node_modules/
        ./qunitjs/
    ./karma/
```

Or use npm in karma folder '`./node_modules/karma/bin/`' or '`./node_modules/karma/`'.

```
cd /home/nik/src/dmt/node_modules/karma/bin/
npm i jquery/qunit
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked this issue out.   Turns out I had to install `qunitjs` *globally* before it worked.

```
npm install -g qunitjs
```

Don't like the solution as it will break module dependancy (for other developers), but seems the only way it worked for me.

I do have Karma installed (via `npm`) globally too, so maybe that's why.